# Vectorized matrix selection based on array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have a `S x n` array `DATA` with data. I have a `(S x 1)` array `ARRAY` with integer values `<=n`. For each row `i` in `DATA`, I want to

```
DATA[i, ARRAY[i]:] = np.nan
```

Here's how I'm doing it right now

```
from numpy.random import poisson as poissonN
from numpy.random import uniform
import numpy as np
S = 1000
n = 8
DATA = uniform(low=0, high=1, size=S*n).reshape((S, n))
ARRAY = poissonN(1, S).reshape((-1, 1))

for i, draw in enumerate(ARRAY):
    DATA[i, draw:] = np.nan
```

There must be a vectorized analogue to this which is more efficient if `S` goes in the hundred thousands, right? Whatever meshing I try, it won't work out - or is equally slow to this iterative approach.

Comment: There might be a fancy index trick to make this work (but I don't know it).  If one doesn't show up, writing it up in Cython might help speed things up if this code snippet becomes a significant bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) -

```
DATA[ARRAY <= np.arange(DATA.shape[1])] = np.nan
```

**Explanation**

Let's take a sample case with `S = 5` and `n=4` and create `DATA` and `ARRAY`.

```
In [288]: S = 5
     ...: n = 4
     ...: DATA = uniform(low=0, high=1, size=S*n).reshape((S, n))
     ...: ARRAY = poissonN(1, S).reshape((-1, 1))
     ...: 

In [289]: DATA
Out[289]: 
array([[ 0.54235747,  0.01309313,  0.62664698,  0.92081697],
       [ 0.17877576,  0.36536259,  0.91874957,  0.81924979],
       [ 0.7518459 ,  0.73218436,  0.99685998,  0.26435871],
       [ 0.73130257,  0.77123956,  0.10437601,  0.09296549],
       [ 0.804398  ,  0.78675381,  0.71066382,  0.87481544]])

In [290]: ARRAY
Out[290]: 
array([[1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [2],
       [1]])
```

Now, run the loopy code and see what happens -

```
In [291]: for i, draw in enumerate(ARRAY):
     ...:     DATA[i, draw:] = np.nan
     ...:     

In [292]: DATA
Out[292]: 
array([[ 0.54235747,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.17877576,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.73130257,  0.77123956,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.804398  ,         nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

Now, with the proposed solution we are creating a boolean array of the same shape as `DATA` such that it covers all `NaN` elements as `True` and rest as `False`.

For the same, we are using `broadcasting` as shown here -

```
In [293]: ARRAY <= np.arange(DATA.shape[1])
Out[293]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Thus, with boolean indexing we can set all those positions as NaNs in `DATA`. Let's create another instance of random elements and test out the NaNs with our proposed approach -

```
In [294]: DATA = uniform(low=0, high=1, size=S*n).reshape((S, n))

In [295]: DATA[ARRAY <= np.arange(DATA.shape[1])] = np.nan

In [296]: DATA
Out[296]: 
array([[ 0.87061908,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.69237094,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.04257803,  0.82311917,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.00723291,         nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

Please note the non-Nan values are different, because we have re-created DATA. The important thing to notice is that we have correctly set `NaNs`.

**Runtime test**

```
In [297]: # Inputs
     ...: S = 1000
     ...: n = 8
     ...: DATA = uniform(low=0, high=1, size=S*n).reshape((S, n))
     ...: ARRAY = poissonN(1, S).reshape((-1, 1))
     ...: 

In [298]: DATAc = DATA.copy() # Make copy for testing proposed ans

In [299]: def org_app(DATA,ARRAY):
     ...:     for i, draw in enumerate(ARRAY):
     ...:         DATA[i, draw:] = np.nan
     ...:         

In [301]: %timeit org_app(DATA,ARRAY)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.99 ms per loop

In [302]: %timeit DATAc[ARRAY <= np.arange(DATAc.shape[1])] = np.nan
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.1 µs per loop

In [305]: np.allclose(np.isnan(DATA),np.isnan(DATAc))
Out[305]: True
```